# Find height of rendered/visible text

Tags: javascript, jquery

I know how to get this height of a font:
[image]

By placing the text in a div and getting offset height of the div.

But I would like to get this actual height (Which will depend on font family):
[image]

Is that in any way possible using web based programming?

Comment: In the first example, why is there padding?

Comment: That's not padding, it's the marked text. So it's natural padding as part of the font family, I guess. That's hat I want rid of.

Comment: @JohnSmith Could you setup a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) demonstrating it so we can play a bit with it? Because that space may have different causes.

Comment: The extra vertical space is due to the descenders, i.e. 'j', 'g', 'y'.

Comment: Ahh I see. Can you provide the font(s) in question?

Comment: Nevermind, I see that now with testing. I never noticed something like that. I found out using a `span` reduces that extra space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was writing the code while Jason answered, but I decided to post it anyway:
http://jsfiddle.net/adtn8/2/
If you follow the comments you should get the idea what's going on and why. It works pretty fast and it's not so complicated as it may sound. Checked with GIMP and it is accurate.

(code to be sure it wont be lost):

```
// setup variables
var c = document.createElement('canvas'),
    div = document.getElementsByTagName('div')[0],
    out = document.getElementsByTagName('output')[0];

// set canvas's size to be equal with div
c.width = div.offsetWidth;
c.height = div.offsetHeight;

var ctx = c.getContext('2d');
// get div's font from computed style and apply it to context
ctx.font = window.getComputedStyle(div).font;
// use color other than black because all pixels are 0 when black and transparent
ctx.fillStyle = '#bbb';
// draw the text near the bottom of the canvas
ctx.fillText(div.innerText, 0, div.offsetHeight);

// loop trough the canvas' data to find first colored pixel
var data = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, c.width, c.height).data,
    minY = 0, len = data.length;
for (var i = 0; i < len; i += 4) {
    // when you found it
    if (data[i] != 0) {
        // get pixel's y position
        minY = Math.floor(i / 4 / c.width);
        break;
    }
}

// and print out the results
out.innerText = c.height - minY + 'px';
```

## EDIT:

I even made jQuery plugin for this: https://github.com/maciek134/jquery-textHeight

Enjoy.

Comment: Thank you Killah, but I can't get it to work properly. I just tried a div with font-size 3cm and it returned 7px as the output.

Comment: Weird, for me it's returning 79px, for both 'normal' and jQuery version:
http://jsfiddle.net/adtn8/4/
http://jsfiddle.net/killah/adtn8/5/
Maybe you are using non-standard font and it's not loaded when you call the function?

Comment: I wouldn't think so. I've tried both on FF and IE. My language is Danish, don't know if that makes a difference? Another thing that's weird; I don't actually see the output in your first example. I had to change it to get the element's ID instead.

Comment: @JohnSmith First, there is no Canvas implementation in IE (unless you use IE9/10 and `<!DOCTYPE html>`). Second, the FF's `window.getComputedStyle` implementation doesn't expose `font` attribute so I had to change my code a little. It works now (the jQuery plugin from repo above).

Answer (score 4):

Is there a simple solution? I think the answer is no.

If you're ok with a more involved (and processor-intensive) solution, you could try this:

Render the text to a canvas, then use `canvasCtx.getImageData(..)` to retrieve pixel information.  Next you would do something similar to what this pseudo code describes:

```
first_y : null
last_y : null
for each y:
    for each x:
        if imageData[x][y] is black:
            if first_y is null:
                first_y = y
            last_y = y
height = last_y - first_y
```

This basically looks for the top (lowest y-index) of the lettering (black pixels) and the bottom (highest y-index) then subtracts to retrieve the height.

Comment: I figured this was the only solution. Thanks Jason, I'll play around with it and see if it's worth it.